# How can i add tab to SAP B1 SystemForm in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, sapb1

I wanna add a new tab to SystemForm in SAP B1 Studio for MS Visual Studio.

I am using C#

Answer (score 1):

Simplest approach to this is to catch the System Form's Load event and call a function like the following (this code adds a tab named "My Tab's Name" to the Business Partner form):

```
    public void BPForm_ItemEvent_Load(String FormUID, ref SAPbouiCOM.ItemEvent pVal, ref bool BubbleEvent)
    {            
        SAPbouiCOM.Button obutton;
        SAPbouiCOM.Item oitem;
        SAPbouiCOM.Item oNewItem;
        SAPbouiCOM.Folder oFolderItem;
        SAPbouiCOM.Form oform;

        oform = HandleSAPB1.SBO_Application.Forms.Item(pVal.FormUID);
        oNewItem = oform.Items.Add("my_tab", SAPbouiCOM.BoFormItemTypes.it_FOLDER);

        oitem = oform.Items.Item("9"); // UI element in the system form to use for positional reference 
        oNewItem.Top = oitem.Top;
        oNewItem.Height = oitem.Height;
        oNewItem.Left = oitem.Left + oitem.Width;

        oFolderItem = oNewItem.Specific;

        oFolderItem.Caption = "My Tab's Name";

        oFolderItem.GroupWith("9");
        oform.PaneLevel = 1;

        UIManager.AddTabElements(oform); // my custom class that adds UI controls to the tab
    }
```

Comment: HandleSAPB1, oFolderItem = oNewItem.Specific; and   UIManager.AddTabElements(oform); give me error  how can i add them to my project? @Overhed

Comment: Sorry, should have commented that call. UIManager is my own custom class which handles some UI work (like adding controls to the tab). You can leave that line out.

Comment: it didnt solve my problem , seem anything when i run the project. @Overhed

Comment: Are you calling the function on the BP Form load event?

Comment: How can i call? @Overhed

Comment: Ahmet, you want to call the function above from your main Add-On Item Event handler function. Take a look at some of the SDK samples on UI API Event Handling.

Comment: How to add SBO_Application to my class? I cant use it @Overhed